# How to put two elements next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put two divs next to each other, but either the one that's supposed to be on the right is showing up below the left one, or they are next to each other, but they're no longer anywhere near the left edge, which is where the left one is supposed to be.

Here is my HTML.

```css
.maincontent {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    font-family: 'Arvo';
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #242424;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    height: 210px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.linkinsidebar {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Arvo';
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <h3 style="font-family:'Arvo';">Jump</h3>

  <a class="linkinsidebar" href="#info">Info</a>
  <a class="linkinsidebar" href="#quiz">Quiz</a>
  <a class="linkinsidebar" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
  <a class="linkinsidebar" href="#top">Top</a>
</div>

<div class="maincontent">

  <p class="pmaincontent">
    <a id="info">Placeholder text</a>
  </p>

</div>
```

[Here is what the code looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0u6U.png)

Comment: You have a stray `body` tag to start with.

Comment: oh no sorry there is a closing body tag there, i just didn't include it in the snippet

Comment: Regardless it's in the wrong place

Comment: Float the sidebar to the left instead of the main content. or look into CSS grid / flexbox

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, you need to add float left and float right in sidebar and maincontent class.
In addition, the HTML snippet contains a body tag in the middle of two divs. It's wrong.

```css
.maincontent {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.8;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    font-family: 'Arvo';
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.sidebar {
    background-color: #242424;
    opacity: 0.8;
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 50px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    height: 210px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    position: sticky;
    float:left;
    top: 0;
}

.linkinsidebar {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Arvo';
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
   <h3 style="font-family:'Arvo';">Jump</h3>
   <a class="linkinsidebar" href="#info">Info</a>
   <a class="linkinsidebar" href="#quiz">Quiz</a>
   <a class="linkinsidebar" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
   <a class="linkinsidebar" href="#top">Top</a>
</div>
<div class="maincontent">
   <p class="pmaincontent">
      <a id="info"></a>
      Placeholder text
   </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Here's the thing. When I run this, they indeed are next to each other, but they're no longer touching the edge. They're just dangling in the middle. https://imgur.com/a/r0g0ERZ

Comment: @packofstains in HTML document, the div is nested in another element, except body?

Comment: actually i just fixed it. both divs are now in the body element, except for the top navigation bar.

Comment: Good.
But, in general, according to W3C, "The <body> element contains all the contents of an HTML document, such as headings, paragraphs, images, hyperlinks, tables, lists, etc."
Therefore, it's a good practice not to have elements outside of it.